# Error in inserting into a table Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying my hands with Mysql 
I have a built a table customers like-

```
$table_customers = "CREATE TABLE customers (
            id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
            email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            gender ENUM('m','f') NOT NULL,
            mobile VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            DOJ DATE NOT NULL,
            activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
            )";
```

The table is successfully built in the database.
Now I query this-

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO table customers(username,name,email,password,gender,mobile,DOJ)
                VALUES ('apple','Apple','apple@gmail.com','pass123','m','99291',now())";
```

The error the script is throwing is -

```
Erreur de syntaxe près de 'table customers(username,name,email,password,gender,mobile,DOJ) VALUES ('ap' à la ligne 1
```

Kindly help in rectifying the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: there is no `table` in an insert query. it's `insert into tablename (... fields..) values (... values...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to specify `table` in the insert query. Below should work:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO customers(username,name,email,password,gender,mobile,DOJ)
                VALUES ('apple','Apple','apple@gmail.com','pass123','m','99291',now())";
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) is the documentation for insert query syntax for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (列1, 列2,...) VALUES (值1, 值2,....)
```